# A getter for dictionary elements in C# 4.0

Tags: c#, dictionary, getter

I want to implement a dictionary that creates its own elements on the fly only when they are accessed (not in advance). To do that I would like to use a getter method, but I simply don't find any information how to declare a getter in the context of dictionary elements.

I do understand how to add a getter to the whole dictionary (which must return a dictionary when called), but what I want to do is implement a getter that is called when a single element in the dictionary is accessed so I can create that element on the fly. That getter must receive the key that is used for the request as a parameter and it must return the corresponding value.

I do not find any syntax for that task in the docs.

Comment: This? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2549tw02(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3587604/are-auto-adding-indexers-on-dictionaries-and-collections-a-good-design-decision

Comment: This isn't a dictionary, it's a cached factory. I'd implement a custom class with a `GetValue(key)` method and a private dictionary field.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to reimplement the indexer on `Dictionary<,>`

```
    public class MyDictionary<TKey, TValue> : Dictionary<TKey, TValue>
{
    public new TValue this[TKey key]
    {
        get
        {
            TValue value;
            if (!TryGetValue(key, out value))
            {
                value = Activator.CreateInstance<TValue>();
                Add(key, value);
            }
            return value;
        }
        set { base[key] = value; }
    } 
}
```

If you need a more sophisticated value instantiation, you can use an activator function

```
 public class MyDictionary<TKey, TValue> : Dictionary<TKey, TValue>
{
    readonly Func<TKey, TValue> _activator;

    public MyDictionary(Func<TKey, TValue> activator)
    {
        _activator = activator;
    }

    public new TValue this[TKey key]
    {
        get
        {
            TValue value;
            if (!TryGetValue(key, out value))
            {
                value = _activator(key);
                Add(key, value);
            }
            return value;
        }
        set { base[key] = value; }
    } 
}
```

Usage:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var dict = new MyDictionary<int, string>(x => string.Format("Automatically created Value for key {0}", x));
    dict[1] = "Value for key 1";
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(dict[i]);
    }
    Console.Read();
}
```

Comment: Whow. Great stuff! Many thanks for pointing me into this direction.

Comment: Kev, I am struggling with the usage of your two classes. Could you edit your answer and give a short usage example for both of them? That would be of great help. Thanks!

Comment: @Jpsy what exactly is your problem? It should be pretty straightforward. See the usage example i added

Comment: I was fiddeling around with the first class and couldn't seem to get id doing anything but storing and retrieving values that were setted/getted from Main. But your edit helped. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

While the answer of Kev is perfectly correct and given on a professional level it still gave me a hard time (and initiated a lot of fruitful learning - thanks Kev!). As you can tell I am a learner of C# and there are many concepts that I still have to assimilate. I want to add an answer to my own question here in case anybody else has the same problem and is on a similar level of understanding as me. Maybe this will save some livetime.

Kev used Generics in his answer - a great concept introduced with C#2. To simplify the answer I want to show it without Generics and with a lot of comments added that give hints to all concepts that I had to look up (and that were partially not easy to find):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace DictionaryElementsGetter_Test {

  // class inherits from Dictionary<int, string>
  public class MyDictionary : Dictionary<int, string> {
    // new: hide element of base class to redefine it in derived class.
    //      see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/435f1dw2.aspx
    // string this[int key]: create an indexer
    //                       (actually: replace the indexer of base class, because of "new")
    //                       see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2549tw02.aspx
    new public string this[int key] {
      get {
        string value;
        // out: pass argument by reference instead of by value
        //      This is the standard definition of TryGetValue.
        //      Beside the bool result that indicates the existence of the key-value-pair,
        //      TryGetValue also returns the value itself into this reference parameter (if key is found).
        //      see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee332485.aspx
        if( !TryGetValue( key, out value ) ) {
          value = "abc" + key + "def";
          Add( key, value );
          // just to see when the getter really did an Add():
          Console.Write( "ADDED!... " );
        }
        return value;
      }
      // base: access element of the base class Dictionary<int, string>
      //       see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hfw7t1ce(v=vs.100).aspx
      set { base[key] = value; }
    }
  }


  class Program {
    static void Main( string[] args ) {

      var dict = new MyDictionary();
      dict[1] = "EXTERNAL VALUE";

      for( int i = 0; i < 3; i++ ) {
        Console.WriteLine( i + ": " + dict[i] );
      }
      /* 
      Output:
        ADDED!... 0: abc0def
        1: EXTERNAL VALUE
        ADDED!... 2: abc2def
      */
      for( int i = 0; i < 3; i++ ) {
        Console.WriteLine( i + ": " + dict[i] );
      }
      /* 
      Output:
        0: abc0def
        1: EXTERNAL VALUE
        2: abc2def
      */

      Console.ReadKey();

    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It's already implemented in the framework. If you call

```
Dictionary<int, string> _myDictionary = new Dictionary<int, string>();

_myDictionary[1] = "Hello";
_myDictionary[2] = "World!";
```

you will have your dictionary populated with the key-value pairs <1, "Hello">, <2, "World!">

Comment: You've demonstrated *setters*; OP is asking about *getters*.

Comment: Sorry Andrew, this is not what I am looking for.

Comment: @Jpsy could you clarify? Do you mean `string aValue = _myDictionary[1]`? If so then you need to be careful as any type that is immutable or a value type cannot be updated once returned